# How to make input attributes required in post body request?

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jersey

Here is my example: 
    Java:

```
 @JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true)
private String deviceName;
```

I made the name as a required field. In request how to make it as required field. I should send the name value from request.

But when I enter this:

```
{ "id": "abc123",}
```

It should send error response back.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Jacksons `JsonProperty` Annotation is not used for Validation. see: [Jackson @JsonProperty(required=true) doesn't throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320731/jackson-jsonpropertyrequired-true-doesnt-throw-an-exception). But you can use [Bean Validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html), e.g.:

```
class Device {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    private String deviceName;
}
```

Comment: But its not working. I annotated deviceName as @NotNull and I am not sending deviceName from postman, it is not throwing error still it is executing with deviceName as null.

Comment: you could try @NotEmpty

Comment: please have a look at this link, how to enable the validation. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13383

Comment: you have to place @Valid at the declared paramter in your resource method, not in the Entity-Class (exceptions are nested beans).

Comment: I added @Valid for bean validation. But it is also not working.

    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response details(@Valid Device device) {

Comment: looks correct! jersey-bean-validation is in your class path?

Comment: Isnt it part of core-jersey?

Comment: no: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I added it and still it is going through. I use gradle so dependency is 
'org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:2.22.2'

Comment: yes: javax.validation.Validation is the right annotation. I think you have the right dependency in your class path. So all should work... please have a look at: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13383

Comment: if you still have a problem registering the entity-validation feature, you could ask another question and show the resource methods, entity class and Application configuration.