# how to use fasterxml.jackson to validate nested case class in scala

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson, fasterxml

I'm new to scala and I encountered a problem to validate free style json vs my predefined case class, assume:

```
case class sth(f1: String,
               f2: Option[String],
               f3: Map[String, sth2],
               f4: Array[sth2],
        )

case class sth2(subF1: String, subF2: List[sth3])
case class sth3(subF:String)
```

I tried Java 8 jackson validator describe in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357713/java-8-jackson-validation/36358018), but how do I define nested case class (within Map and Array) and throw custom exception message?

Many thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: show us your problem? what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) package that partially solved my problem, but need to manually define json schema for it to work