# How to make deserialization fail with Jackson when JSON is incomplete?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a simple JSON file and a corresponding Java class. I want that the deserialization process fails if the JSON file misses one of the properties from the Java class or a property is `null`. I tried several things e.g. `@JsonIncludePropertie`s or Jacksons deserialization features `FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES`, `FAIL_ON_NULL_CREATOR_PROPERTIES`. No luck. Also I could not find any help form the Jackson documentation. I almost think that isn't possible at all.

JSON file:

```json
{ 
  "propA": "foo",
  "propB": "bar"
}
```

Java class:

```java
public class Props {
  public String propA;    
  public String propB;
}
```

I skiped the boilerplait code like getter or setter to make the example as small as possible.

Comment: The Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13768738/6044791 doesn't solve my question but explains why I could not find any solution.

Comment: Look at the other answers too, there are some solutions although they do come with some caveats.

Comment: Thx I already considered it and implemented it with Bean Validation.

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Comment: No it's perfectly fine and will help people who search for similar keywords instead of "required".